# optimistic concurrency with neo4j using the REST API

Tags: neo4j

Is there any way to implement optimistic concurrency during updating and creating neo4j nodes using the REST API?  I'd like to create a user node with a unique name only if that name doesn't exist.  Don't want two users to accidentally overwrite each other if they pick the same username at the same time.

Additionally, I'd could also have something like an incrementing version number to check for concurrency on the node.  In SQL I would normally have an update with a where clause that checks for id and version number.  Is there something similar I can do with cypher that would be easy to implment and wouldn't require me to type all the property names out into a long query?

Answer (score 2):

You could try a unique index: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-unique-indexes.html

Cypher "CREATE UNIQUE" syntax may also be a help: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-create-unique.html

Comment: wouldn't that still allow the concurrency exception in creating the nodes?  i.e. both nodes still have to be created before the indexes is added and by the time the unique index check returns an existing index entry both duplicate nodes can have already been created.  As for the "create unique" cypher query, that can overwrite or duplicate one with the other rather than throw an exception.  i.e. if 2 objects {uname:"mike", pwd:"test"} and {uname:"mike", pwd:"monkey"} were both sent using the same cyhper query there would be two nodes with the same uname since their pwds were different.

Comment: The unique node creation via the REST API takes the correct index-locks to prevent duplicate node creation.